Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS error during boot
Every now and then since I installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 in a dual boot on my hp omen 15 laptop this screen appears during boot that does not let me proceed further and after waiting several minutes nothing happens, the screen remains.

Looking around the first errors are just warnings, the last errors should be related to the video card and bluetooth.
Being a complete beginner I wanted to ask your opinion on what to do to avoid doing damage.
Thanks in advance to whoever answers and forgive me if I have written both informatics and grammatical inaccuracies(I'm using google translate).
These are my PC specs:
BIOS:
Version F.53
Date 4/24/2024
Motherboard:
Manufacturer HP
Model 8600
Version 44.48
Operating System:
Edition Microsoft Windows 10 Home (64-bit)
Version (Build) 22H2 (10.0.19045)
Processor:
Intel Core i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
Graphics:
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060
Audio:
Intel Smart Sound Technology
Realtek High Definition Audio
NVIDIA High Definition Audio
Networking and I/O:
Intel® Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
Realtek Gaming GbE Family Controller
Thunderbolt Controller 1
Intel Wireless Bluetooth
Memory:
16 GB
Storage:
Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB
ST1000LM049-2GH172

"Good morning": Here is afternoon and in some other places in the world it is midnight. The messages on the photo do not indicate any boot problem. Please [edit] your question and remove irrelevant greeting and add more information. For example, what happens if you wait a few minutes? What happens if your press Ctrl+Alt+F4 or Ctrl+Alt+Del? What type of hardware are you using? And why are you using the 20.04 tag?

@FedKad Thanks for replying, as soon as it appears I will use Ctrl+Alt+F4 or Ctrl+Alt+Del and update the post with the results.

did you install nVidia driver as part of install by choosing to install the optional or restricted drivers. If not can you boot to grub menu with escape key just after UEFI/BIOS screen but before grub menu normally appears. And boot in recovery mode? At command line it then is like a server install: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation Do you have UEFI Secure boot on? If so you also have to provide a MOK or machine owner key to authorize a proprietary driver.  Is Windows fast start up on, needs to be off.

@oldfred Thanks for the reply, after clicking on revert in additional drivers and following the steps to install the NVIDIA drivers from the link you provided, I did several reboots, the last one after about an hour without ever encountering the problem.
I will see if during the next few weeks the problem reappears, if so I will update the post, thanks to both of you for the help.
